# How to export data from firestore in a cost-effective manner for data analysis?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, data-analysis

I am looking for a way to get the data in my company's firestore database without it costing too many reads, it is a huge database and currently, it is not an option to export it regularly due to cost, I need a reasonable sample size if not all the content in the database to run some analytical work using either python or R.

Comment: The only way you will get data out of Firestore is by reading documents.  Those reads cannot come more cheaply than they already do.  You should be mirroring data to another source that's cheaper to query, such as BigData.

Comment: Any recommendation for how I could go about doing that?